# Stuck with a complex query in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 models in Mongo DB.

```
User 

Posts - Linked to userid

Comments - Linked to userid
```

I need to fetch the below columns as a final result.

```
Username  |  UserEmail  |  TotalPostsbyUser  |  TotalCommentsbyUser
```

Right now to achieve this I'm using multiple async loops. Is there anyway I can fetch the required results in a single query? Similar to joins in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use should use [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)
But it might be not the best approach for doing this.
If you need to query it many times, you should cache those number in some where else.

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        username: "USERNAME" // or any other condition here
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
       from: "posts",
       let: { "userId": "$_id" }, 
       pipeline: [ 
           { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$owner", "$$userId"] }}}, 
           { $project: {_id: 1}} ] // I assume that the foreign key is "owner"
       as: "posts"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "comments",
        let: { "userId": "$_id" }, 
        pipeline: [ 
           { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$owner", "$$userId"] }}}, 
           { $project: {_id: 1}} ] // I assume that the foreign key is "owner"
        as: "comments"
    }
},
{
 $project: {
   Username: "$username",
   UserEmail: "$userEmail",
   TotalPostsbyUser: { $size: "$posts"},
   TotalCommentsbyUser: { $size: "$comments" }
 }
}])
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:  `Total size of documents in posts matching pipeline exceeds maximum document size`

Comment: @Anirudh Yes, this will happen as array (posts and/or comments) causes the parent to exceed the 16MB BSON Limit. Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size

Comment: Can you post your query here?
You should limit your query data by $match expression
Another, you can try using $project in pipeline in $lookup to get only _id field

    
    `$lookup: {
        from: "posts",
        let: { "userId": "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$owner", "$$userId"] }}},
          { $project: {_id: 1}}
        ],
        as: "posts"
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining collections and then counting in project stage, you need to count in lookup stage only, otherwise it will not work for large datasets:

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        username: "USERNAME" // or any other condition here
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
       from: "posts",
       let: { username: "$username"},
       pipeline: [
        {$match : {"username" : "$$username"}},
        {$group : {_id : "$username", "post_count" : {"$sum : 1"}}}
       ],
       as: "posts"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "comments",
        pipeline: [
          {$match : {"username" : "$$username"}},
          {$group : {_id : "$username", "comment_count" : {"$sum : 1"}}}
        ], 
        as: "comments"
    }
} 
])
```